# How should I embedded a tabHost into every Activity in my App

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I wrote a Tabhost below:

```
public class AppTabhost extends TabActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /**find tab host**/
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    /**add tabs**/
    //tab 1
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost
            .newTabSpec("tab1")
            .setIndicator("tab1")
            .setContent(new Intent(AppTabhost.this, anotherActivity.class)));

    //tab 2
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost
            .newTabSpec("tab2")
            .setIndicator("tab2")
            .setContent(new Intent(AppTabhost.this, theotherActivity.class)));
}
```

I want to  put it on the bottom of every Activity in my App

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could slap an Intent in there like

```
Intent I= new Intent(this, Apptabhost.class);
startIntent(I);
```

But if you want the tabhost to be physically at the bottom of the screen, I would suggest you define a class that will extend tabhost and not tabhost activity. Since a view hierarchy contains views and not activities.

Comment: now that i re read the question do you want the tabs on the bottom of the screen with the content on top?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put it in bottom the you can write this code

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

on your tabHost activity xml file